# how can i access the object properties that have spaces

Tags: json

in the below json file i want to access the "personal details", but how can i do that, it different from other object keys.

```
{
"data": {
    "personal details": {
        "name": "Loren",
        "father's name'": "Geroge",
        "mother's name": "Lita"
    },
    "class": {
        "name": "Loren Gothem",
        "class": 7,
        "division": "3rd"
    },
    "address": {
        "temporary address": "Acn Block Ist Phase",
        "permanent address": "Bozane Trail Building Ist Floor"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access using bracket notation

```
data['personal details']
```

same for all the other keys with spaces as well as with a single word

```
data['personal details']['name']
```

but it's better to use `.`dot notation for single word json keys

```
data['personal details'].name //  "Loren" 
data.address['temporary address'] // prints "Acn Block Ist Phase"
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure about your requirement but expecting below snippet may help

```
var a = {
"data": {
    "personal details": {
        "name": "Loren",
        "father's name'": "Geroge",
        "mother's name": "Lita"
    },
    "class": {
        "name": "Loren Gothem",
        "class": 7,
        "division": "3rd"
    },
    "address": {
        "temporary address": "Acn Block Ist Phase",
        "permanent address": "Bozane Trail Building Ist Floor"
    }
  }
};

// with JQuery
$.each(a.data, function(i,j){
document.writeln(JSON.stringify(a.data[i]));
})

// with Javascript for..each loop
for(b in a.data){
    document.writeln(a.data[b].name);

//  if(b == "personal details"){
//      do something else
//  }

}
```